# How to grab text data from Google search info bar

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I need to grab text data from google search engine info bar. If someone use a keyword "siemens" to search on google search engine. A small info bar appear right side one the google search result. I want to collect some text information for that info bar. How can I do that using requests and Beautifulsoup. here some on the code I write.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests
from googlesearch import search
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?ei=j-iKXNDxDMPdwALdwofACg&q='


com = 'siemens'

#for url in search(com, tld='de', lang='de', stop=10):
#    print(url)

response = requests.get(url+com)
soup = BS(response.content, 'html.parser')
```

Red marked area is info bar

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the find function in BeautifuLSoup to retrieve all the elements with a given class name, id, css selector, xpath etc. If you inspect the info bar (right click on it and give 'inspect') you can find the unique class name or id for that bar. Use that to filter the info bar alone from your entire html parsed by BeautifulSoup.

Check out find() and findall() in BeautifulSoup to achieve your output. Always go for finding by id first, since every id is unique to an html element. If there is no id for that, then go for the other options.

To obtain the URL, use google.com/search?q=[] with your search query inside []. For queries with more than one word, use a '+' inbetween

Comment: But you need url to go that particular page where google show all the results. I don't have url of that particular page. I am using 'search' for 'Googlesearch' package.

Comment: You can use google.com/search?q=[ ]. Provide your search terms inside the bracket. Use + to separate words. for eg: if your query is "Top movies of the year", you need to give q=Top+movies+of+the+year

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using `user-agent` to fake real user visit, otherwise it might lead to a blocked request from Google. [List](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/edge) of user-agents.

To visually select elements from a page, you can use [SelectorGadgets](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab CSS selectors.

Code and [example in online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scraping-Google-Search-Knowledge-Graph-python-serpapi#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=simens', headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

title = soup.select_one('.SPZz6b h2').text
subtitle = soup.select_one('.wwUB2c span').text
website = soup.select_one('.ellip .ellip').text
snippet = soup.select_one('.Uo8X3b+ span').text
print(f'{title}\n{subtitle}\n{website}\n{snippet}')
```

Output:

```
Siemens
Automation company
siemens.com
Siemens AG is a German multinational conglomerate company headquartered in Munich and the largest industrial manufacturing company in Europe with branch offices abroad.
```

Alternatively, you can use [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "simens",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

title = results["knowledge_graph"]["title"]
subtitle = results["knowledge_graph"]["type"]
website = results["knowledge_graph"]["website"]
snippet = results["knowledge_graph"]["description"]
print(f'{title}\n{subtitle}\n{website}\n{snippet}')
```

Output:

```
Siemens
Automation company
http://www.siemens.com/
Siemens AG is a German multinational conglomerate company headquartered in Munich and the largest industrial manufacturing company in Europe with branch offices abroad.
```

> Disclaimer, I work at SerpApi.